# Get a DocumentReference without providing an ID in Firebase 9 web version Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to commit a batch write using **firebase 9** modular sdk. This operation includes creating a **post** document, ideally with an auto generated id.

```js
const batch = writeBatch(db)
const postRef = doc(db, 'posts') // this fails, must pass and id
const threadRef = doc(db, 'threads', post.threadId)
batch.set(postRef, post)
batch.update(threadRef,
    'posts', arrayUnion(postRef.id),
    'contributors', arrayUnion(state.authId))
await batch.commit()
```

In **Firebase 8** it's possible to obtain a document reference with a random generated id using with the following code.

```js
firebase.firestore().collection(nameOfTheCollection).doc()
```

I'm trying to accomplish the same thing using **Firebase 9** modular sdk, but I can't find any method to do this.
Is it possible to get a document reference with a ***random generated id*** without creating the document first with ***Firebase 9***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#doc_2) function and pass a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference) as first parameter *without* any path segments as shown below:

```
import { doc, collection } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(collection(db, "colName")); // Don't specify an ID yourself

console.log(`New Document ID: ${docRef.id}`);
```